# How to get the current list/library name using JSOM?

Tags: 2010, jsom

How to get the current list/library name using JSOM? So far I found two snippets which return GUID of the current list/library, but not the name.

```
// Using standard JSOM
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()

// Using SP Services
$().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl()
```

I would prefer something which would not go for server callbacks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ctx` to get current list/library info. For `Name` or `Title`, It is

```
ctx.ListTitle
```

**PS:** No callback needed

Following information can be retrieved from `ctx` about current list/library in SharePoint 2010.

```
 [   "listBaseType", "listTemplate", "listName", "view", "listUrlDir",
    "HttpPath", "HttpRoot", "serverUrl", "imagesPath", "PortalUrl",
    "RecycleBinEnabled", "isWebEditorPreview", "rootFolderForDisplay",
    "isPortalTemplate", "isModerated", "recursiveView", "displayFormUrl",
    "editFormUrl", "newFormUrl", "ctxId", "CurrentUserId", "isForceCheckout",
    "EnableMinorVersions", "ModerationStatus", "verEnabled", "isVersions",
    "WorkflowsAssociated", "ExternalDataList", "HasRelatedCascadeLists",
    "CascadeDeleteWarningMessage", "ContentTypesEnabled", "SendToLocationName",
    "SendToLocationUrl", "StateInitDone", "TotalListItems", "CurrentSelectedItems",
    "LastSelectableRowIdx", "SelectAllCbx", "TableCbxFocusHandler", "TableMouseoverHandler",
    "existingServerFilterHash", "NavigateForFormsPages", "OfficialFileName", "OfficialFileNames",
    "WriteSecurity", "SiteTitle", "ListTitle", "isXslView", "clvp"
]
```

To find above info, paste the following line in browser's console.

```
console.dir(Object.keys(ctx))
```

Unfortunately, It is not documented by *MSDN*. The all we have for exploring it is: Browser's console.

Comment: You mean like this `SP.ClientContext.get_current().ListTitle`?

Comment: No ... It will return the currently opened list in the browser. Try it in the browser console

Comment: Nopes, ctx is an list object having almost every data present in the list. You need to just write :- var listtitle=ctx.ListTitle;

Comment: @AtishDipongkor sorry i didnt saw ur comment

Comment: You gave a better explanation than me! @AzamKhan

Comment: @AtishDipongkor: Thanks! It worked. But do you have any information on this `ctx` variable? Any MSDN documentation? How does it get generated? With everyone writing `var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();` will this cause any issue?

Comment: Yup ... `ctx` is a global variable. `var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();` means you are overriding it. so it will be an issue.

Comment: `ctx` is only availble on list view pages, not on list item forms, unfortunately. Not sure if it's relevant, but make sure you double check.