# 'ctx' variable in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, jsom

Recently I came across the variable `ctx` ([link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/165784/20540)) in SharePoint which allows you to get the name of current list/library without any fuss. Apparently the `ctx` variable has quite few more tricks up its sleeve. It can return values like, GUID of list/library, site title, no. of currently selected items and more.

But I cannot find any MSDN documentation for this variable. Is the use of this variable supported by Microsoft? I am currently developing on SP 2010 so I can verify that it works there. But what about SP 2013? Also with every example for JSOM starting with `var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();` we are bound to override this useful variable.

Comment: ``var ctx`` *inside* a function will create a locally scoped variable, *not* overriding ctx in the global scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ctx` is a global variable. It belongs in the list view pages.

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

So if you use above line in any list view pages, it will cause an issue. The value of `ctx` will be overridden by  `SP.ClientContext.get_current();`. You will not get any info from `ctx` after above line.

In SharePoint 2013, it works and widely using in [CSR](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views). It has more info than in 2010. Following things we can get from `ctx` in SharePoint 2013

```
["listBaseType", "listTemplate", "listName", "view", "listUrlDir", "HttpPath", "HttpRoot", "serverUrl", "imagesPath", "PortalUrl", "RecycleBinEnabled", 
 "enteringGridMode", "inGridMode", "isWebEditorPreview", "rootFolderForDisplay", "isPortalTemplate", "isModerated", "recursiveView", "displayFormUrl", 
 "editFormUrl", "newFormUrl", "ctxId", "CurrentUserId", "isForceCheckout", "EnableMinorVersions", "ModerationStatus", "verEnabled", "isVersions", 
 "WorkflowsAssociated", "ExternalDataList", "HasRelatedCascadeLists", "CascadeDeleteWarningMessage", "ContentTypesEnabled", "SendToLocationName", 
 "SendToLocationUrl", "StateInitDone", "TotalListItems", "CurrentSelectedItems", "LastSelectableRowIdx", "SelectAllCbx", "TableCbxFocusHandler", "TableMouseoverHandler",
 "onItemSelectionChangedHandlers", "wpq", "Templates", "ListData", "ListSchema", "BaseViewID", "ListTemplateType", "existingServerFilterHash", "noGroupCollapse", 
 "NavigateForFormsPages", "BasePermissions", "CurrentUserIsSiteAdmin", "IsAppWeb", "AllowGridMode", "rootFolder", "viewTitle", "NoScriptEnabled", "OfficialFileName", 
 "OfficialFileNames", "WriteSecurity", "SiteTitle", "ListTitle", "isXslView", "IsClientRendering", "RegionalSettingsTimeZoneBias", "CanShareLinkForNewDocument", "SiteTemplateId", 
 "bInitialRender", "ListDataJSONItemsKey", "ControlMode", "SiteClientTag", "CurrentLanguage", "CurrentCultureName", "CurrentUICultureName", "OnPreRender", "OnPostRender", 
 "canDragUpload", "RenderView", "RenderHeader", "RenderBody", "RenderFooter", "RenderGroups", "RenderItems", "RenderFields", "RenderFieldByName", "heroId", "CurrentItem", 
 "CurrentItemIdx", "CurrentFieldSchema", "fHidden", "clvp", "queryString"]
```

- Total number of properties of `ctx` in 2010 is 49
- Total number of properties of `ctx` in 2013 is 94

If you have multiple lists in a page, then you will have multiple `ctx`.

[image]

I have two lists in a page. My `ctx`'s are `ctx37` and `ctx73`

**PS:** Unfortunately, It is not documented by *MSDN*. The all we have for exploring it is: **Browser**'s console.

Comment: note that ``ctx`` has different content when the page is being built. Javascript variables are passed by reference so the ctx objects you check (after the whole page was loaded) is the Final ctx object. If you want to play sleuth use ``console.log(ObjectUtil.deepCopy(ctx))`` inside called function to see what ctx was at time of execution. (**)