# How do I get the ID of the current Discussion Item using Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, discussion-board

How can I dynamically get the ID of the current discussion thread in javascript?

Currently, I have the following code:

```
function submitReply() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var discussionItem = ctx.CurrentItem;
    var body = CKEDITOR.instances['commentArea'].getData();

    var messageProperties = {'Body': body}; 
    createMessage(discussionItem,messageProperties,
        function(){
            console.log('Reply has been post successfully');
        },
        function(sender,args){
             console.log('Error occurred while posting a reply:' + args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
```

[image]

When I use **ctx.CurrentItem** the return value is null.

[image]

Here is the link to my complete code: https://pastebin.com/jNFbUBaB

Comment: what do you mean by **current discussion thread**?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor It means that the discussion that you are viewing.

Comment: line `var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();` is not need.

Comment: just call your function like `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
   submitReply();
});`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get it from `ctx`. See [more](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/165827/21421) about `ctx`.

## Current Discussion Item

```
var discussionItem = ctx.CurrentItem;
```

## Current Discussion Item ID

```
var discussionItem = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
```

You need to ensure that `sp.js` is load in the page.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function() {
   submitReply();
});
```

No need of line `var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();`

## Update

If discussion thread contains any reply, then `ctx.CurrentItem` does not work. In that case, solution is:

```
var discussionItem = ctx.ListData.Row[0];
```

[image]

Comment: I have try this solution on my site. But the return value of ctx.CurrentItem is null. I don't know what is wrong. Could you help me with this? @AtishDipongkor

Comment: How are you using it? Can you show me your code? update your question with code.

Comment: you need `var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); `. `ctx` is a global variable. So you dont need to declare it. see https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/165827/21421

Comment: call your `submitReply()` from `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
     submitReply();
});`

Comment: Here is the link to my complete code https://pastebin.com/jNFbUBaB. It's still not working. @AtishDipongkor

Comment: remove line `var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();` and try

Comment: updated paste bin https://pastebin.com/rx45nh9K

Comment: the value is still null. @AtishDipongkor Can you show me your code? Did you just simply open the discussion and type in ctx.CurrentItem to get the value?

Comment: Yes. I opened and typed it

Comment: I've just figure why this doesn't work? If you only have the Discussion Title, then it will work. However, when you reply to it, and then type the command ctx.CurrentItem it won't work anymore. I think this is because the newly created reply has ID so it can't return the thread ID anymore.

Comment: Ok. Then use `ctx.ListData.Row[0]` must work. try it instead of `ctx.CurrentItem`

Comment: That works as expected!!!

Comment: excellent. nice to hear that!